# Rotate by an angle theta on y-axis a joint oriented in Euler angles

Tags: matlab, rotation

I have a joint (of a human skeleton) with no translation (located at the origin with X,Y,Z = 0,0,0) and orientation defined in Euler angles (e.g. X = -111 degrees, Y = 82 degrees, and Z = -123 degrees), as shown in the figure below:

[image]

I want to rotate that joint by an angle theta (e.g., θ = -60 degrees) on Y-axis (e.g., the orientation will be X = -165 degrees, Y = 22 degrees, and Z = -173 degrees), as shown in the figure below:

[image]

I want to implement a function for that rotation, but I cannot get the maths. One of my thoughts was to convert the Euler representation to a vector, then rotate, and then get back the Euler angles, but I cannot figure how to convert these Euler angles to an orientation vector, and then how to get back the Euler angles from the rotated vector.

Thanks

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/help/robotics/ref/eul2rotm.html

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. I know this function but unfortunately this is not what I am looking for. The joint orientation is defined in Euler angles, and I am looking for a method (+ the maths) that can rotate the orientation of the joint by an angle theta on Y-axis.

Comment: I believe that with some work over the Euler functions described and [vvrotvec2mat](https://se.mathworks.com/help/sl3d/vrrotvec2mat.html) you probably manage that.